# How to use mouse drag gesture to position & size a still image in Premiere Pro CS6

Tags: premiere, cs6

I would like to be able to position a still image using the mouse/pointer directly on the image, to be able to drag the whole image around or resize it by dragging one of its corners or sides.

I'm sure I did this earlier but don't know which part of Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 does it.

Sure, there's the Effect Controls but this seems to only provide for indirectly resizing and positioning the image - i.e. I mouse drag on the numbers themselves and see the effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply double click the Sequence Preview and you get handles to resize the footage and you can drag the footage around in the frame.

[image]

Comment: +1 accepted. Got it! It was that double-click - thank you so much!

Comment: One more thing - what if there are several tracks of still images overlapping - how do you choose which one to manipulate?

Comment: Premiere will choose the one you double click on, just make sure you haven't selected one already, it wont select a different image when there is one already being selected.
The topology in the timeline is also a factor, even if an image is not visible it will still be selected when double clicked on.

Comment: Thanks but not sure if I'm seeing that happen myself. For example if I have a title on top of an image, I always get the title moving when I click. Presumably a solution is to turn off the title, or just temporarily move it elsewhere to get at the image to move that (which I actually did in the end.) Cheers!

Comment: It depends on the layer size, if the layer is full frame with surrounding alpha it will still select the layer even when double clicked in the alpha part where a different layer is visible, its similar behavior as in Photoshop.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. ;c Clicked and double clicked everything I saw.